# C++ Code not working due to ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false). Make this work or suggest other code for taking I/O in Fastest way

Tags: c++, input, io, c++14, user-input

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    inline void fast(int &n)
    {
        n = 0;
        register int c;
        bool negative = false;
        c = getchar();
        while((c < 48 || c > 57) && c != '-' )
            c = getchar();
        if(c == '-')
        {
            negative = true;
            c = getchar();
        }
        while(c > 47 && c < 58)
        {
            n = (n<<1) + (n<<3)+ c - 48;
            c = getchar();
        }
        if(negative)
            n *= -1;
    }

    int main ()
    {
        ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL); cout.tie(NULL);
        int a,b;
        string s;
        fast(a);
        fast(b);
        cin >> s;
        cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
        cout << s;
        return 0;
    }
```

**I WROTE THIS CODE FOR FASTEST INTEGER INPUT USING getchar() AS WELL AS OTHER INPUTS FAST using CIN IN COMPETITIVE PROGRAMMING.**

> **INPUTS :**

> **1.** 1 2

> hello
> (inputs not in a single line)
> this works, here **'enter'** is pressed before giving input 'hello'.

> **2.** 1 2 hello
> (inputs in a single line)
> **not working after pressing 'enter'. Has to give input again. It works perfectly well without ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false).**
> This is **BREAKING** the Code  by removing the sync.

**IS THERE ANY WAY TO SOLVE THIS AND MAKE 1 2 HELLO WORK
SO AS TO TAKE INPUT IN THE FASTEST WAY
or SUGGEST ANY OTHER METHOD or CODE !!!**

***Also can you please suggest Fastest method for INPUT and OUTPUT of INTEGERS as well as STRINGS for Competitive Programming!!!***

Comment: Why don't you remove `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);`? The point of that is to remove synchronization between `cin` and `getchar` (which uses `stdio`). That is exactly what you are seeing. If you want sychronization then don't call `synx_with_stdio(false)`

Comment: You know it almost like you've copied some code from somewhere without understanding what that code does, and it turns out the code you've copied does exactly the opposite of what you wanted. This is known as [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: Indiscriminately using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` are both bad. I advise you find a better source to learn and practice C++.

Comment: I have now posted my original question. I hope now you will understand why i used the previous code. Please help me solve it now.

Comment: You do know you can use iostreams to read character input right?

Comment: I wrote this code to use fastest available methods for taking integer and other INPUTS. Can you provide a solution or provide any other method for Fastest Inputs from input stream ?

Comment: What's more important, fast or working? If you insist on using the code that is breaking it then you need to choose iostreams or stdio, you can't use both.

Comment: Then can you suggest any other method or code for taking FAST Inputs without breaking ?

Comment: The entire purpose of `ios::sync_with_stdio(false)`, etc. is so you can use iostreams with less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a month ago. You should not use NULL in `cin.tie() and cout.tie()` instead use '0' inside it.

```
ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(0);
cout.tie(0);
```

This should work fine.

Comment: It's not working. Try all inputs in same line and then press "enter".